# How to execvp with two main functions in C?

Tags: c, execvp

I am trying to use `execvp` in my code but I am having trouble. For example purposes, let's say I have two .c files called `1.c` and `2.c`. In `1.c` I need to `fork()` to make a parent and child <s>class</s> process, all included in main(). In `2.c` is a function to countdown from 5 to 1, all included in main() as well. My question is, how do I use `execvp` from `1.c` to execute `2.c` in the parent? Whenever I try to compile, it keeps giving me an error saying redeclaration of `main`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post your code and state what problem your having with that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `execvp()` to execute a new program.  By the sounds of it, you need to compile `1.c` to make program `1`, and you need to compile `2.c` to create program `2`, and you need program `1` to `fork()` and the child to `execvp()` program `2`.  They are, however, separate executables, each with its own `main()`.